# Pass value to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am creating a app in which i wanna slide images,so for that i will be using view pager.For the image i have created a fragment which will display the images.
Code

```
public class ImageSwitcher extends BaseFragment {

    private ImageView imageView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_switcher_fragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_switcher);
        imageView.setBackgroundResource("");
    }
```

Now at this line

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource("");
```

the image will come from the int array which i will pass.
My doubt is

1. How will i pass int values to fragments
2. Is there any better way to use image switcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_BG_RES="ARG_BG_RES";

public Fragment() {}

static public newInstance(String backgroundRes) {
   Bundle args = new Bundle();
   args.putExtra(ARG_BG_RES, backgroundRes);
   Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
   fragment.setArguments(args);
   return f;

void whereYouNeedIt() {
   String backgroundRes = getArguments().getStringExtra(ARG_BG_RES);
   ...
}

}
```

From outside:

```
MyFragment f = MyFragment.newInstance("black");
```

Don't omit `public Fragment() {}` it's required by the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Pass your `Integer` value from your fragment using `Bundle` as below:

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putInt("id", id);
 fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Access the value in Fragment `onCreateView` method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     int m_id=getArguments().getInt("id");

return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bundle` to pass values to the fragment or during initializing pass values via a `custom` constructor

For background resource if you are not changing images based on some logic in code, apply it via XML background and a drawable :-/

Comment: Custom constructor won't do for Fragments. When recreating Fragments OS have no way to know you have a custom constructor and will try to use the default one. It then attaches the arguments from the previous instance to the fragment

Comment: yup, for that you have the saveInstance to save the state in bundle and restore it later. Thats how it should be done as per the life cycle

Comment: If you are using Fragment's saveInstance you will have to save your Fragment in Activity's onSaveInstanceState and restore it in onCreate why bother.

Comment: how do you plan to restore the original state when the fragment or activity is recreated

Comment: By finding the fragment and, if not exists, by instantiating it